# Why would MySQL leave out the first row when retrieving from a database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For some reason I'm having a problem retrieving data from my database. It leaves off the first item being listed.

Connection:

```
mysql_select_db($database_my_db, $my_db);

    $query_rs_jobboards11 = "SELECT * FROM jobBoardsSpecTypes ORDER BY type";
    $rs_jobboards11 = mysql_query($query_rs_jobboards11, $my_db) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_rs_jobboards11 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_jobboards11);
    $totalRows_rs_jobboards11 = mysql_num_rows($rs_jobboards11);
```

Output:

```
 <form action="" method="get">
        <select name="specialty">

         <?php do { ?>

    <option value="<?php echo $row_rs_cms11['type']; ?>"><?php echo $row_rs_cms11['type']; ?></option>


    <?php } while ($row_rs_cms11 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_jobboards11)); ?> 


        </select>

<input type="submit" value="Go" />

</form>
```

It keeps leaving out the first entry in the type column. If I add more entries, then the one that was left out previously is shown, and the new entry is hidden.

What am I doing wrong? The database works perfectly fine for everything but this page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You already assigned the first row to `$row_rs_jobboards11`, so when you call `$row_rs_cms11 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_jobboards11)` in your do/while loop, it's starting at the second row in the table.

Using a do/while instead of a while doesn't make any difference, but using different variable names does make a difference.

**Update, to explain the difference between while, do/while, and, making sure your variable names are correct.**

While loop, which works:

```
while ($row_rs_cms11 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_jobboards11)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    //stuff here
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

do/while loop, which also works

```
$row_rs_cms11 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_jobboards11);
do {
    echo '<tr>';
    //stuff here
    echo '</tr>';
} while ($row_rs_cms11 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_jobboards11));
```

Note that the $row variable matches. If you leave out the first call, it will still work, but you'll get an extra (empty)  before any content is outputted. If you set the variable to a different name (and use a mysql_fetch_* call), the internal database pointer is set to the second row in the table. Consequently, you miss the first row in the table, because it's set to a different (unused) variable.

Moral of the story:

You can use either a while or a do/while loop, you just have to make sure that

- If you are using a do/while, the row variable must be created *prior* to entering the loop. And,
- Make sure your variable names match!

Comment: Hmm... this is only one of the problems. Do-while instead of while does indeed make a difference here because $row_rs_cms11 is assigned in the condition. With do-while the variable doesn't have any value in the first run of the loop...

Comment: That's because $row_rs_jobboards11 was how the variable was instantiated, instead of $rs_jobboards11 which is used in the loop (note the extra $row_). A do/while works perfectly  fine if you make sure you're using the proper variable.

Comment: Though there's no apparent advantage of a do/while instead of a while loop here. There could be e.g. if another action is taken if the result set is empty. But then either calling mysql_num_rows() or the duplication of the fetch_assoc() code is most likely superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using do-while instead of while. At your first iteration $row_rs_cms11 is undefined.

Comment: Yep - always use a while loop

Comment: Specifically, it's undefined because the OP set the first row to $row_rs_jobboards11, so the internal pointer is looking at row 2.

Comment: @dcaunt: No. Know what you're doing when you use a do-while loop is the correct answer.

Comment: @davethegr8 : you are correct, that is the root cause of the problem, I didn't check that part. Should give an answer so it is accepted :)

Comment: With his 'connection' code, changing do while to while will still miss the first row (as it has already been retrieved)

Answer (score 2):

You are using $row_rs_cms11 where you really meant $row_rs_jobboards11 ($row_rs_cms11 is not defined the first time around).

```
    <?php do { ?>

<option value="<?php echo $row_rs_jobboards11['type']; ?>"><?php echo $row_rs_jobboards11['type']; ?></option>


<?php } while ($row_rs_jobboards11 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_jobboards11)) ?> 


    </select>
```

The error would have been more evident if you had used while() instead of do {} while().

If you change the do {} while() to while() as has been suggested, you need to remove the  part of your code where you fetch $row_rs_jobboards11 for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

On the very first iteration of your do/while loop, the `$row_rs_cms11` is not set.  It is set on the next iteration by the `while` code, but the first time through it is blank.  I believe you have simply mis-named a variable.

Change this:

```
$row_rs_jobboards11 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_jobboards11);
```

To this:

```
$row_rs_cms11 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_jobboards11);
```

Better yet, don't do that first `mysql_fetc_assoc()` call at all, and simply change your `do/while` loop to a `while` loop only, and the first row will be read there instead.